# F#: n-ary tree extract single element and save computations

Tags: f#, tree

Given the type for a tree:

```
type id = int;;
type tree = T of id * tree list;;
let ex = T(12,[T(3,[T(4,[T(38,[])])]);T(23,[T(22,[])]);T(1,[])]);;
```

Given that all id's are unique I would like to get a tree from a given id like so:

```
get 23 ex = t(23, [t(22,[])]);
```

So far I only been able to make a function like this:

```
  let rec child c n = 
    match c with
    | [] -> []
    | e::es -> (get n e) @ (child es n)
   and get id t = 
    match t with 
    | T(id1,c) when id=id1-> [t]
    | T(_,c) -> child c id;;
```

Which is fine, but the function does a total run through of all nodes in the tree. Is it possible to make a function that terminates when it finds the right node and thereby skips some computations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make the recursive call return a value that somehow contains the response about whether it found the node. If it did - just return it, if it didn't - keep (recursively) searching the rest of the tree.

To do this, F# has a handy built-in type - `Option`. It's a sum type defined as `type Option<'t> = Some of 't | None`. So I would make the `get` function return an `Option<tree>` rather than `tree list`, and then the `child` function can decide whether it wants to proceed:

```
 let rec child c n = 
    match c with
    | [] -> None
    | e::es -> match get n e with
               | Some x -> Some x   // node found - just return it
               | None -> child es n // not found - keep searching
   and get id t = 
    match t with 
    | T(id1,c) when id=id1-> Some t
    | T(_,c) -> child c id;;
```

Also note that your `child` function is actually available in the standard library under the name of [`List.tryPick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.trypick%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let rec child c n = List.tryPick (get n) c
```

Which makes the whole thing collapse into this:

```
let rec get id t = 
    match t with 
    | T(id1,_) when id=id1 -> Some t
    | T(_,c) -> List.tryPick (get id) c
```